# How do you get xcode to edit SWIFT argument values without losing the argument name?

Tags: xcode, swift

When adding a call to a function while editing objective-c is xcode, tabbing through the arguments highlights only the values and setting them is straightforward.

[image: objective-c works great]

For SWIFT however, both the argument name and the value are highlighted and attempting to set the value deletes the argument name.

[image: SWIFT highlights both argument name and value]

How do I get xcode to not highlight and then lose the argument name? [Note: xcode version is 7.1.1]

Comment: Is this only in regards to the `C` function in your example, or is this for any and every method in `Swift`? This is important because the `C` functions just work like that when used in `Swift` and you can't change this. However, you do have control over what is highlighted and what isnt with methods you create in `Swift`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, the behavior of the tab is correct. The argument name *should* be deleted as you are constructing the call, because it is not an *externalized* argument name.

Note the declaration:

```
public func CVPixelBufferCreateWithPlanarBytes(allocator: CFAllocator?,
 _ width: Int, 
 _ height: Int, 
 // ...
```

The `_` means that the external names have all been suppressed. This method is called like a C function (just a sequence of comma-separated argument values) — because in reality it *is* a C function:

```
CV_EXPORT CVReturn CVPixelBufferCreateWithPlanarBytes(
    CFAllocatorRef CV_NULLABLE allocator,
    size_t width,
    size_t height,
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on wether the initializer or function you're calling have external names or not. If an external name exists, tabbing will position you into sending an argument for this external name. If none exists, XCode autocompletion shows the *internal name*, for you convenience, but in the initalizar/function, a lack of external name means you should only send the value.

Example:

```
class MyClass {
    var myInt : Int
    var myString : String

    init(myInt: Int, myString: String) {
        self.myInt = myInt
        self.myString = myString
    }
}
```

When calling the initializer above, the external names are set as equal to the internal names by default, for all initializer parameters, and XCode will autocomplete according to:

`var a = MyClass(myInt:`<kbd>Int</kbd>`, myString:`<kbd>String</kbd>`)`

Whereas for the following example:

```
func foo(_ a: Int, _ b: String) { 
// ...
}
```

no external name exists (supressed by `_` prefix to internal names in function signature), and when calling the function, XCode will autocomplete by *showing you* the internal names, however marking the full internal name + value part to be overwritten:

`foo (`<kbd>a: Int</kbd>`,`<kbd>b: String</kbd>`)`